# How to redefine proof?

Tags: environments, theorems

I want to define a new proof environment. I have defined it as below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}~[\citenum{#1}]}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     citecolor    = blue
}



\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\centering}

\newtheorem*{proofs}{Proof S}

\begin{document}

\begin{proofs}
There are many things 
\end{proofs}

\end{document}
```

See the compiled document:

[image]

Question: there are two problems, first why it is bold and second text is in italics? I also want to define a proof command in which output should be "proof of theorem 4", etc.

Comment: In `amsthm`, `proof` is not defined as a `\newtheorem`, but is separately defined in a quite different manner.  Your use of the default theorem style is the reason that the text is italic and the heading is bold.  You can change the style of the text to roman by specifying `\theoremstyle{definition}` but that will not change the heading style.  The existing `proof` definition accepts an optional heading text that can do what you say you want, e.g. `\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{<label>}]`.  Consult the `amsthm` user guide for details (`texdoc amsthdoc`).

Comment: Suggest an alternative or some other easy way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Isn't that what @barbarabeeton just provided?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand what you want, but if you simply need another proof environment with reference to a theorem, you can take advantage of the optional parameter of the proof environment, as Barbara said, and create a new environment with the label of the reference as a parameter.

Off-topic: you loaded `cleveref` twice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}~[\citenum{#1}]}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     citecolor    = blue
}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndEnvironment{quote}{\centering}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{proofs}[1][]{\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem \ref{#1}]}{\end{proof}}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{theo:my}
here is my theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{proofs}[theo:my]
There are many things 
\end{proofs}
\end{document}
```

[image]